# Remove array element from document matching a field in array element

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, studio3t

I have a document looking like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f60ffc5aefd067a9ff9345c"),
    "_class" : "com.kalsym.smart.sms.data.MSASMS",
    "number1" : NumberLong(923211105469),
    "numbers2" : [ 
        {
            "field1" : "20200915532E888",
            "number2" : NumberLong(923018565627),
            "field2" : "abcd",
            "datefield" : ISODate("2020-10-10T17:54:09.886Z")
        }, 
        {
            "field1" : "2020092570A6948",
            "number2" : NumberLong(923018565627),
            "field2" : "efgh",
            "datefield" : ISODate("2020-10-06T15:23:04.891Z")
        }, 
        {
            "field1" : "2020092570A6948",
            "number2" : NumberLong(923018565627),
            "field2" : "ijkl",
            "datefield" : ISODate("2020-10-03T15:23:04.891Z")
        }
    ],
    "optInCount" : 0
}
```

I want to delete array indices containing *datefield* value greater than *2020-10-04*

After executing the command document must be updated like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f60ffc5aefd067a9ff9345c"),
    "_class" : "com.kalsym.smart.sms.data.MSASMS",
    "number1" : NumberLong(923211105469),
    "numbers2" : [ 
        {
            "field1" : "2020092570A6948",
            "number2" : NumberLong(923018565627),
            "field2" : "ijkl",
            "datefield" : ISODate("2020-10-03T15:23:04.891Z")
        }
    ],
    "optInCount" : 0
}
```

Comment: What language do you want to implement this? And please show your working code in that language.

Comment: I want to execute this query in shell using Robo 3T client

Comment: You should add [robo3t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robo3t) tag to your question.

Comment: As per your expected result, How `"datefield" : ISODate("2020-09-03T15:23:04.891Z")` is greater than `2020-10-04` this date? also what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry my mistake I have update the question with proper dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html) or `update()`, and `$pull` to remove matching record form array,

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
{
  $pull: {
    numbers2: { datefield: { $gt: ISODate("2020-10-04T00:00:00.000Z") } }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pYsJS-uCs45)